# Quarkus Java logs are not retrieved in Opentelemetry receiver

Tags: java, apache-kafka, openshift, quarkus, open-telemetry

I have deployed a quarkus application in openshift and annotated the deployment with
opentelemetry auto-instrumentation.

The problem is that I can able to retrieve the metrics and traces. But logs are missing.

**Annotation CLI command is**

> oc patch deployment.apps/quarkus-app -p '{"spec":
> {"template": {"metadata": {"annotations":
> {"instrumentation.opentelemetry.io/inject-java": "true"}}}}}'

This is my auto-instrumentation yaml

```
apiVersion: opentelemetry.io/v1alpha1 kind: Instrumentation metadata:  name: demo-autoinst   namespace: opentele spec:   propagators:
    - tracecontext
    - baggage
    - b3   sampler:
    type: parentbased_traceidratio
    argument: "1"   java:
    image: ghcr.io/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-operator/autoinstrumentation-java:latest
    env:
      - name: OTEL_EXPORTER_OTLP_ENDPOINT
        value: "http://url:4317"
```

This is my collector yaml

```
apiVersion: opentelemetry.io/v1alpha1
kind: OpenTelemetryCollector
metadata:
  name: demo
  namepsace: opentele
spec:
  image: ghcr.io/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-collector-releases/opentelemetry-collector-contrib:0.78.0
  config: |
    receivers:
      otlp:
        protocols:
          grpc:
          http:

    processors:
      batch:
    
    exporters:
      logging:
        loglevel: info

      kafka/logs:
      brokers: 
        - url:9092
      topic: all-logs-1
      encoding: otlp_json
      protocol_version: 3.4.0 

    service:
      pipelines:
        traces:
          receivers: [otlp]
          processors: [batch]
          exporters: [...]

        metrics:
          receivers: [otlp]
          processors: [batch]
          exporters: [...]

        logs:
          receivers: [otlp]
          processors: [batch]
          exporters: [logging,kafka/logs]
          
  mode: deployment
  resources: {}
  targetAllocator: {}
```

Can anyone help me on this.

Answer (score 1):

Quarkus has not yet support for OpenTelemetry (OTel) Metrics and Logs. It is planned.
You have OTel Tracing and Micrometer metrics with the [Quarkiverse's OTLP registry](https://github.com/quarkiverse/quarkus-micrometer-registry/tree/main/micrometer-registry-otlp).

Please mind that the OTel Agent is not recommended to use with Quarkus because it doesn't properly handle context propagation between imperative and reactive code.

You have a demo app, with Micrometer and OTel tracing sending data with OTLP, as an example here: https://github.com/brunobat/quarkus-observability-demo/tree/main/quarkus-observability-demo-micrometer